# Mixing OR & AND mysql query wrong results (laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am using eloquent the query builder, and this is what a specific query produces:

```
select * from `articles` where (select count(*) from `authors` where `authors`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` and `author` like ?) >= 1 or `title` LIKE ? and `approved` = ? or (select count(*) from `tags` where `tags`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` and `tag` like ?) >= 1 or `abstract` LIKE ? or `description` LIKE ? and `year` NOT LIKE ?
```

The problem is this query still produces results with year like the result, as opposed to results with the year NOT LIKE as stated.

This is what I get when I return `$query->toSql()`. The query itself is dynamically built with `Laravel` `Eloquent` with a mix of where, `orWhere`, `whereHas` and `orWhereHas`, however if I can understand what is wrong with this *query* I should be able to get closer to the problem.

Comment: [operator precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html). Since you're mixing and/or, **YOU** have to tell mysql what order they should be parsed in, and that means adding `()` as appropriate.

Comment: **P**EMDAS.  Parenthesis delegate order in the case of logical math.

Comment: we always used BEDMAS - (b)rackets (e)xponents (d)ivision (m)ultiplication (a)ddition (s)ubtraction.

Comment: Thanks all, helped a lot! Parenthesis in the right spots did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT *
FROM   `articles`
WHERE   (
        ((SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   `authors`
        WHERE  `authors`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id`
               AND `author` LIKE ?) >= 1)
        OR (`title` LIKE ?)

        OR ((SELECT Count(*)
            FROM   `tags`
            WHERE  `tags`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id`
                   AND `tag` LIKE ?) >= 1)
        OR (`abstract` LIKE ?)
        OR (`description` LIKE ?)
        )
        AND
        (`year` NOT LIKE ?
           AND `approved` = ?)
```

Comment: Thank you, parenthesis in the right spots did it for me.